# Mouse Drag in C# UNITY3D?

Tags: c#, mouse, unity-game-engine

I need to move a cube by clicking and dragging in C# Unity3D. My code currently creates the cubes by cilcking a button.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CDraggable : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Texture btnimg;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    Update () 
    {
        //here to write mousedrag code.
    }

    void OnGUI() 
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(400, 250, 50, 50), btnimg))
        {
            //Debug.Log("Clicked the button with an image");
            GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            cube.transform.position = new Vector3(-0.7F, 2, 0);
        }
    } 

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a forum for you to ask others to do your work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Add the script `DragRigidbody.js` to your camera.  It is included in unity's default assets at `StandardAssets/Scripts/GeneralScripts/`, and it does exactly what you want.

Comment: While it's the result the OP wants, it's not the language they wanted.

Comment: @Byte56 I'm sure it could be ported to C# easily, if the OP decided it was worth that effort.  Unity doesn't mind mixing and matching.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.. :)

```
Vector2 screenPoint = Vector2.Zero ;


void OnMouseDown()
{
    screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(scanPos); 
    offset = scanPos - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(
        new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
}

Vector3 curScreenPoint = Vector3.Zero;
Vector3 curPosition = Vector3.Zero;
void OnMouseDrag()
{
curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);

    curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint) + offset;
    transform.position = curPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help if your game is 2D, I think.

```
void Update{  
if (Input.GetMouseButton())
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }
}
```